# Not able to fetch resultset in Hibernate using HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I'm triggering a query using HQL, normally it should return empty resultset as it doesn't have any records w.r.t it. But, it throws

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
```

My code is

```
String hql = "FROM com.pck.Person where userId = " + userId;
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);         
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Dashboard> listUserDetails = query.list(); <-- Problem here.
```

I'm expecting list size is 0 because there are no records w.r.t userId passed.

What changes do I need to do?

Comment: you are missing single quotes around `userid`. Try with "FROM com.pck.Person where userId = '" + userId + "'";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say the value of userId was "abc12"

Given your code, the value of the string called hql would become:
"FROM com.pck.Person where userId = abc12"

If you took the value of that string and tried to run it as a query on any database, most of them would fail to understand that abc12 is a string. Normally it would be interpreted as a variable.

As other users mentioned including the single quotes would produce the desired query, but the recommended way to assign parameter values is this:

```
  String hql = "FROM com.pck.Person where userId = :id"
  query.setParameter("id", userId);
```

Comment: Cool.. But what exactly is the diff?

Comment: i'd need more of the stacktrace to be more specific

Comment: It is of alphanumeric type.. not exactly long or int

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing single quotes around userid.

Try with `"FROM com.pck.Person where userId = '" + userId + "'";`

or

Use named parameters with `query.setParameter("userid", userId);`

Posting the full stacktrace would help if this doesn't solve.